# Possible to do ordered dictionary in python 2.5 (due to GAE)?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, dictionary, python-2.5

I'm new to Python, and using Google App Engine, which is currently running only Python 2.5.  Are there any built-in ways of doing an ordered dictionary, or do I have to implement something custom?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django provides a SortedDict class, which has the same functionality. If you are using django, you can just use `from django.utils.datastructures import SortedDict`.

Even if you're not using django, you can still take advantage of that implementation. Just get the datastructures.py file from the django source and save it somewhere importable.

http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/utils/datastructures.py

Comment: `SortedDict` is a misnomer - it maintains insertion order and does not sort, for example, by the dict key.  It is more like `OrderedDict`.  Also see http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ordereddict which can also be dropped in.

Answer (score 0):

you can sort a `dict.items()` list (of tuples) .. can't?

Answer (score 0):

OrderedDict is new in 2.7, so no, there's no built-in way to do this - you'll have to implement your own.

Usually, an ordered dictionary is implemented as a dictionary of linked list nodes, linked in traversal order. This should be fairly straightforward to implement yourself.